# Парсинг html разметки средстами PHP

Tags: php, парсер, php-curl

Есть у меня вот такой код.

```
<?php
    $urls = 'https://aliexpress.com/item/32825297510.html';

    $ch = curl_init($urls);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.google.com/');

    curl_multi_add_handle($multi, $ch);

    $channels[$row[0]] = $ch;

    $content = curl_multi_getcontent($channel);
?>
```

Как мне правильно парсить HTML разметку из переменной $content?

Comment: var_dump($content) что выводит?

Comment: Выводит только footer.

Comment: Но бывает и всю страницу загружает. Раз через раз.

Comment: Есть множество библиотек-парсеров с развернутым и понятным функционалом -Вам обязательно именно с этим кодом что-то делать?

Comment: Правильно парсить через библиотеку php_simple_html_dom